How to combine the first row and second row into a new row in a new column in Power Query?
I need help in cleaning up data in Power Query. I'm trying to make another column based on the description column. How can I create a new column that will combine the current row and the next row as the current row for the new description column? Please see sample image below.
Thank you so much!


I don't think there's a way to do this directly, but if you export the table to excel you could write a formula that if the cell below on the date column is null then combine the description of the current row and row below it, then re-query it to remove the null dates and old description column.

Yes, I think that will be the case. Thanks for sharing!

While it's an extra step it should be relatively easy to execute. I would suggest other approaches in Power query; however, seeing some of the dates won't have a second row would eliminate those as alternatives.

I think I can easily fill the rows with null dates... what other approaches do you have in mind if date column will not have any null rows?

So if in power query every other row needs to be combined with the row above it. You can duplicate the query but start the indexing for one at 1, 0 for the other and merge the queries so it offsets the rows with the one they're meant to combine with. But it needs to alternate. If you bring it to excel you can write a quick IF statement that does it. Then massage it as needed back in power query as a second query. No need to maintain formulas, just refresh one then refresh the other

If( isblank( [row below]), [Desc1] &" "& [Desc2], [Desc1]) Is the general idea if you bring it to excel and then back into power query just remove those null dates, and the old description column so you're left with nonblank dates and the combined descriptions

Hi, thanks! I found a workaround: duplicated the table, prep and then merged them. :)

Awesome, glad you worked it out. If you did something different than my recommendations, you can post an answer to your own post so the internet can learn from your solution. Just explain it as if someone is cluelessly trying to follow along

Combine alternate rows for the Description column in Powerquery
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Offset = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source) & {List.RemoveFirstN(Source[Description])},Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"offset"}),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Offset,{"Description", "offset"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Description"),
#"Alternates"=Table.AlternateRows(#"Merged Columns",1,1,1)
in #"Alternates"



It appears from your example that you have some dates with only a single row description, and other dates with a two-row description.
If that is truly the case, the following code should work:

Add an Index column
Use the Index to reference the next row.

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom Description", each try if #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Date] = null then [Description] & "#(lf)" & #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Description] else [Description] otherwise [Description]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Date] <> "")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"

If you might have dates with more than 1 or 2 rows of descriptions, you can use the following code (slightly slower than the above)

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Group Dates" = Table.Group(Source, {"Date"}, {
        {"Custom Description", each Text.Combine([Description],"#(lf)"), type text}},
        GroupKind.Local, (x,y)=>Number.From(y[Date]<>null))
  
in
    #"Group Dates"


